# Call to require('../../../wp-blog-header.php') results in 404 error?

Tags: theme-development

I've got a button in theme options that calls a file called color.php, (the contents of which are below).

On certain installations of the theme, the script is generating a 404 error and failing unless I take out everything above the //do something line. Any suggestions on what might be causing it?

```
<?php
require('../../../wp-blog-header.php');

if (!is_user_logged_in()){
    die("You Must Be Logged In to Access This");
}
if( ! current_user_can('edit_files')) {
    die("Oops sorry you are not authorized to do this");
}
 //do something
 ?>
```

Comment: If you hardcode the url does it still 404? If so , use a proper pathing for your `require`.

Comment: Yes, according to chrome developer tools, it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a 404 error, it’s a server error. You are calling `is_user_logged_in` and `current_user_can` probably before the definition is loaded. Hook your check to an action where these functions are known, `admin_init` for example.

Comment: Thanks toscho, chrome developer tools is reporting it as a "404 error". I'll try your suggestion: add_action( 'admin_init', 'function_name' );